# php change the string into time format

Tags: php, date

In php I have time like this

```
$time = '2015-06-29T16:00:00Z';
```

I want to convert that time like this format `Tuesday, December 16, 2015 3:00 PM`

For that I tried 
`echo date( 'jS F Y', strtotime( $time) );`

but it is showing time like `1st January 1970`
So can someone help me to get the actual time format as I want.

Comment: There are multiple date times.

Comment: Check the update in the answer, you will get that format.

Answer (score 3):

A simple `DateTime` class usage should suffice, just feed it into the constructor, the just use `->format` and provide the desired output format:

```
$time = '2015-06-29T16:00:00Z';
$date = new DateTime($time);
echo $date->format('jS F Y');
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/19tIhK)

Comment: But I want the date and time should come like Tuesday, December 16, 2014
 3:00 PM

Comment: @NewUser simple, just provide that format accordingly, `echo $date->format('l, F d, Y g:i A');` here's the reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Just pass proper format parameters to it.

```
$time = '2015-06-29T16:00:00Z';
echo date( 'l, F j, Y g:i A', strtotime( $time) );
```

Comment: be careful when exploding if the OP wants to preserve the zulu time, you'll get the default timezone instead

Comment: Hmm.. You are right.. but OP wants the updated answer.. So that will not matter i think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateTime class for better handling of dates

```
$time = '2015-06-29T16:00:00Z';
$dateTime = new DateTime($time);
echo $dateTime->format('l, F d, Y g:i A');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = '2015-06-29T16:00:00Z';
echo date( 'l, F j, Y H:i A',strtotime($time));
```

`l, F j, Y H:i A` can be re-ordered to change the output.

About date function, http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score -1):

Use preg_split:

```
$parts = preg_plit("/Z/",$time);
$parts = preg_split("/T/",$parts[0]);
$theDate=$parts[0];
$theTime=$parts[1];
$what_you_want=date(strtotime($theDate." ".$theTime);
```

Note that you can still change the format of the output.